# Module 'Mixpanel' not found. mixpanel-iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods, mixpanel

**Integration Method:** CocoaPods
**Xcode Version:** 12.1
**Library Version:** 3.6.3
**Platform:** iOS
**Language:** Objective-C
**Description:** Issue when integrating Mixpanel Notification Service, Module Mixpanel not found in NotificationService.h
**Expected Behavior:** For the Notification Service target to work properly following Mixpanel documentation.

I followed the steps in Mixpanel/Mixpanel-iphone [Readme](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/blob/master/README.md). Because the website [documentation](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/ios-push-notifications) has a typo for Rich Push Notifications  NotificationService.h being repeated should a one .m file.

I followed everystep well, installed the pods but I couldn't run no matter what. Because we use Flipper the usage of use_frameworks! gives us some issues. I have tried use_frameworks! :linkage => :static instead and some workaround to make use_frameworks! works. I tried changing Require only App-Extension-Safe Api to No, adding Mixpanel path to Podfile, adding paths to Notification target build settings all didn't work and I get Module 'Mixpanel' not found in NotificationService.h

I also tried starting everything over as I thought maybe my project got corrupted. I see Mixpanel being installed with pods but I cannot import it from NotificationService.h

Here the end of my podfile:

```
target 'NotificationService' do
  pod 'Mixpanel'
end
```

Here is my NotificationService.h file:

```
@import Mixpanel;

@interface NotificationService : MPNotificationServiceExtension

@end
```

Is there any solution to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: did you already try deleting the derived data or pod install ?

Comment: I cleared cache of pod, and deleted pods before installing them again multiple times. I also tried updating XCode and starting over.

Comment: If you can't use_frameworks! can you try importing the header file for `MNNotificationServiceExtension` class. ?

#import <MixPanel/MPNotificationServiceExtension.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have **use_frameworks** enabled in Podfile for both host and extension targets. Then you can import the header file in your NotificationService Extension as shown below to work around this module not found compiler error.

FYI; I was able to import the module just by including **use_frameworks** option in pod file.

[image]